Navigation to file on parameter with Custom Helpers for cshtml
I have a custom helper @Url.Content("./customfolder/typescript.ts", ContentExtension.ToJs) that alters the file and directory. But I lose the functionality to navigate to the original file.
public static string? Content(this IUrlHelper helper, string contentPath, ContentExtension? ext = null) {
        ....
    return contentPath;
}

The param contentPath when used I would like to have a navigation on it just like the original @Url.Content function.

Hi Bas, could you the method you have tried ? We need to do some test.

The method we used was @Url.Content(".dist/scripts/customfolder/typescript.js") but we created the method above to use the link of the TypeScript file (bijv.: './typescript/customfolder/typescript.ts') because thats where we work with and output will be the link shown above.

I have no idea what your question is, not what "the file and directory" is, I advise to elaborate a bit on the question, also: what have you tried, what did you expect, what failed, etc?

Formatting note: Inline code is formatted with backticks (\``). The double star (**`) you used is for bolding. I adjusted the question accordingly.

What do you mean by "have a navigation to it"?

Within VisualStudio i think Intellisense creates a link to the file with the original helper. So if you use the Content method you can click on it to go to the file.
With my custom helper the path can't be clicked on.
Simple as that, my question is is there a way i can fix this so navigation in my code is easier instead of constantly searching for the correct file
